# Add custom properties to .tt POCO classes lost on updating model

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, poco

I've created a 3-tier web application using EntityFramework Database first approach. I need to add custom properties to POCO classes that do not exist in the database. However when I update my edmx and Run Custom Tool for the tt file, my classes get refreshed as per the database and I lose the custom properties I created.

I need such custom properties in my web application only, and I can't add them to the Database. Is there a way to refresh the POCO classes without losing the custom properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way entity works. Those classes will always be refreshed when you run the tool. To accomplish what you are trying to do you need to add the new properties or methods on a different file. The auto generated classes are marked partial for that reason. Here is a link of situation similar to yours http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/31/entity-framework-using-partial-classes-to-add-business-logic-and-validation-to-generated-entities/